# How should I install and add babel plugins and presets to Nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js

I've seen the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#babel) and I know I should use `nuxt.config.js` for it, but it doesn't explain the process of installation.

Answer (score 3):

You can check this [issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1776#issuecomment-435325882)

which point to [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/18j0jkn72q)

Basically, you should modify your `nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
  build: {
    // Add custom plugins or presets through the `babel` object
    // Docs: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#babel
    babel: {
      plugins: [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator", { proposal: "minimal" }]
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Nuxt pre-installs a whole range of babel presets which you can view in the node modules folder of your project. If what you need is not already there you should be able to install it with a simple

```
npm install --save what-you-need
```

then you can utilise it in nuxt.config.js by finding the build object and adding it as the docs show. Your file may differ from the docs as you may have a "module.exports" rather that "export default" but it should work all the same. So you should end up with something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',

  /*
  ** a few other things like head, css, modules...
  */

  build: {
      babel: {
        presets: ['what-you-need']
      }
  }
}
```